# Дождаться полной загрузки старинцы

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Собственно грузится страница, выполняются кое какие действия, в итоге нужно подождать загрузки страницы и кликнуть по определенному элементу, если запустить это все в одном потоке то все нормально, если допустим в 10 то в некоторых потоках почему то не работает данный код, хотя визуально форма загрузилась и элемент доступен.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(360));

wait.Until(w => w.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[@class='select2-result-single']/li[7]/div/div")).Any(o => o.Displayed));
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь следующим кодом

```
public static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
        }
        return driver.FindElement(by);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не помогло, эффект тот же, элемент есть на странице, она полностью загружена, а вебдрайвер не может его найти, хотя в другом окне на такой же странице все находит